# Network.setCacheDisabled does not disable caching

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on a chrome extension that attaches the debugger then sends a command to the debugger using chrome.debugger.sendCommand to set up some settings.

This seems to work correctly in the case of using the `Network.emulateNetworkConditions` and `Emulation.setCPUThrottlingRate` apis, however it doesn't appear to work for `Network.setCacheDisabled`.

This is the function for sending the command that isn't working:

```
function setCacheDisabled(tabId) {
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    chrome.debugger.sendCommand(
        {tabId}, "Network.setCacheDisabled", {cacheDisabled: true}, function() {
            console.log("cache conditions set: "); 
            resolve();
        }
    );
});
```

and prior to this, the debugger is attached with:

```
function attachDebugger(tabId) {
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    chrome.debugger.attach({tabId}, "1.0", function() {
        resolve();
    });
});
```

To test if it's working I'm making sure I have the 'Disable Cache' checkbox not selected in my chrome debugger, clearing all previous network request logging in the network tab, then running the code to attach the debugger and send the message and finally refreshing. After the refresh, I look in the network tab and I see "(from disk cache)" in the size column for many js, csv and svg files. I expect to see the size of the file (showing it was downloaded fresh), same as I see when I manually select the 'Disable Cache' checkbox.